# What are best coding practices for SFDC?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I was searching on net for best coding practices and found many like which focus on one item for ex. no soql in loop and things like that but did not find consolidated list. So here posting this question here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best list of best practices :

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Also if you have any doubts you can always ask more specific question on forum. 
(I quite often make some assumptions - cause Apex is very Java-like language ;) )

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is great start but There are only 10 items in there. i created this thread with hope that it will become consolidated list of best practices.

Comment: To be honest - I think those are quite enough :)
If I may ask - what is missing there in your opinion?

Comment: - Custom settings should be used for eg, user messages, error messages instead of hard coded stings.

Comment: Trigger code is should be centralized

Comment: Try and use before trigger is possible instead of after trigger.

Comment: There are so many ...  i think .. i should consolidate and post my findings till now ... and then we can go ahead from that point.

Comment: That is why there are "best practices" for different aspects of SF along with WIKI's. Entire books have been written covering various facets of this very broad subject. Far too much too cover in a single post here.

Comment: may be ...may be not.... i will post my research here mostly  in next week then then we can decide. I am not expecting full explanation on why and how on each item, unless expert want to post it. I am just happy with the points which will help every new developer i guess.

Comment: Rather than comments, you can try to update/edit and create a community wiki answer. That will make more sense and would be easier to read.

Comment: But custom settings should never be used for error messages. Never.

Comment: This should help you in your learning and understanding the best practices for a developer to follow in salesforce.
http://developer.force.com/BestPractices?categoryId=a0e30000000GuoUAAS

Answer (score 1):

always use a trigger broker framework.

I highly recommend this one:
https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework